# Plot 2D line in polar form having one end at r=0 within matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, logarithm, polar-coordinates

I am trying to plot some data in a polar form all starting from r=0. I successfully plot them using a linear scale. However as soon as I start using a log scale, the result is weird. I get a marker at the beginning and the end of the line, but no line between the marker... I found a workaround by setting the origin of the line to r=0.1 and the line appears. However if I set a smaller value (r=0.001 for example), I am bumping again in the same bug, but the origin of the coordinate is shifted to the left which is unexpected. Do you know any workaround, so that I can plot in log a line starting from r=0 to some r?

Here is a mwe:

```
import pylab
import numpy

R = [0.001,1]
Theta = [0,0]

fig = pylab.figure()
host = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
host.plot(Theta,R,color='r',ls='-',lw=2,marker='D',ms=6)
host.set_rlim(0)
host.set_rscale('log')
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because log(0.0) is -infinity.

```
In [3]: math.log10(0.3)
Out[3]: -0.5228787452803376

In [4]: math.log10(0.1)
Out[4]: -1.0

In [5]: math.log10(0.01)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[5]: -2.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [6]: math.log10(0.001)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[6]: -3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [7]: math.log10(0.0001)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[7]: -4.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [8]: math.log10(0.000)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                       
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)                                                                                                                                                                       
<ipython-input-8-bc8e35603e36> in <module>()                                                                                                                                                                                                      
----> 1 math.log10(0.000)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

ValueError: math domain error
```

You need to consider your starting points for log scales carefully and if you would like it to start from the "0" point your values need to start from 1, (`log10(1.0) = 0.0`).

Comment: That's obvious of course. I forget that's setting the log scale to 0 set_rlim(0) means setting the log and itself the x value. I will try putting 1 instead of 0.1 to have a look... Obvious math but confusing

Comment: Well shifting the null value to 1 did shift my plot, so I end up by using 0.1 instead and it works...

Answer (score 0):

While `Steve Barnes` is exactly correct, this is not the whole story. There seems to be something odd in the way `matplotlib` treats logarithmic polar plots.

A small piece of sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# exponential spiral
theta = np.linspace(0, 20*pi, 10000)
r = np.exp(-theta)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rscale('log')
```

This gives something odd:

[image]

This could be a problem with the y limits:

```
>>> ax.get_ylim()
(5.1579e-28, 0.0001)
```

The lower limit equals to the lowest value in the R data, so that looks fine. However, the upper limit is odd (the highest value in the data is 1), and the spiral does not look like an exponential spiral on log scale (linear spiral).

If I force the y limits (or r limits):

```
>>> ax.set_rlim((r[-1],1))
```

the limits are changed, the graph is not. What is most interesting is that if I put the cursor to the outer end of the spiralette, the value of `r` as reported by the graph window is 1. If I place the cursor to the outer edge, the value is quite close to `1 / r[-1]` (i.e. 2 x 10^27).

So, it seems that at least in some versions of `matplotlib` (I have 1.3.1) the logarithmic polar plot is broken. My guess is that the problem is somehow in hwo the logarithmic Y scale and `transfomr_non_affine` in `polar.py` interact.